# How to break row ("clear" element) in css flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to "clear" element in a "display: flex" container?

I want to achieve something like this:

- 20 elements in a row on a big screen
- 10 elements in a row on a smaller screen
- 5 elements in a row on a small screen

With floats, I could "clear" after each 5th element with proper media queries...

Comment: Why don't you just resize your flex container to accommodate the number of items on each line and let them wrap organically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @ BoltClock suggested you can "resize your flex container to accommodate the number of items on each line and let them wrap organically".

If you want to actually clear a line similar to using floats you can set a margin in the direction you want to clear.

```
element{
  margin-right: calc( 100% - widthOfelement);
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent{
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px grey dashed;   
}

.child{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px orangered solid;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

/*add "clear" after first child*/
.child:nth-child(1){
  margin-right: calc(100% - 100px);
}

/*add "clear" after third child*/
.child:nth-child(3){
  margin-right: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 43):

You can add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container and set the width of the elements inside.

Then you should have the control to decide on which elements the floating will stop.

Demo: http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard

Comment: Ah damn, I accidentally downvoted this and now it won't let me change it unless you edit your answer... If you'd like, go ahead and edit it a bit and I'll come back to change my vote!

Comment: @peterjmag Just passing through and saw that. I cleaned up the answer, you can upvote him now.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to add a **width with percentages** to the elements inside the **container**, along with the property `flex-wrap: wrap`. Then, with a media query, you manipulate the width of said elements given a breaking point. Here is an example:

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element {
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .element {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```